# Odd Hadoop behavior, master performing all work?

Tags: hadoop, cpu-usage

I have setup a cluster using this guide: https://medium.com/@jootorres_11979/how-to-set-up-a-hadoop-3-2-1-multi-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-nodes-567ca44a3b12

Currently I have one datanode and one master node.

What happens when I run a Hadoop job is that, the datanode's network activity indicates that it is sending a lot of data and the namenode receives that data. Also, the namenode's CPU is utilized fully while the datanode's CPU is not used at all. See the figure:

[image]

The nodes are VMs on the same machine. This happens for several different scripts, the figure is from running a WordCount algorithm.

Why is the work not being performed on the datanode? What could cause such a behavior?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the guide, *mapred-site.xml* was not changed. This means that the default values are used. The default for mapreduce.framework.name is "local". This means that all calculations will be performed locally. This must be changed to "yarn".

I created the following *mapred-site.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name> 
   <value> $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*
        $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
    </value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I also had to change *yarn-site.xml* to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
   <value>hadoop-master</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

After restarting yarn and Hadoop, everything worked as expected. The work is performed at datanodes.